# Using CSS animation while javascript computes

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, css-animations

I am developping a web application that needs to generate and compute a bunch of arrays at startup. I would like to show a loading page while this occurs, and maybe play a little with css animations, but it seems that CSS animations will hang while javascript is executed. I already have a loading bar that is updated on key events of the processing, but I would like to use css-transitions to smooth it a bit.

I was wondering if there is any way to let something animate while the javascript is executing?

I know I can manage to give back control to the browser from time to time to let it refresh, but I find it silly that computing something in background with javascript just freeze your whole interface.

EDIT: Here is a dumb example of what I am talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/YWefx/13/ 
If you disable the css transitions, the bar is updated on each iteration, but if you enable it, the transition will only occur at the very end. So I end up with either having to wait 400ms between each loop, loosing 4 seconds doing nothing but animations, having a smooth animation at the end (loosing the benefits of displaying a progress bar), or not animating the bar.

Comment: What about using jquery animation?

Comment: What about just using gif image?

Comment: I believe that jquery animations have the same limitations, that is that any intensive computation will freeze them down. As for gif image, they would work for a repeating "waiting" icon, but not for smooth effects in a loading bar for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS3 animations do not get blocked by Javascript unless there is some intense processing going on (in which case you could get stutters).

If you are triggering them during the load I could see them getting delayed until they get to that portion of the script.

One way around this is to setTimeouts at the very beginning of the script to trigger animation changes at certain times.

Another (perhaps better) option would be to use keyframes.  Make sure to call this before the loading begins. http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-animations/#keyframes

Comment: This won't answer his question. If javascript locks the browser thread (long running series of code), CSS animations will STOP. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Shmiddty/8p5Ah/1/ The animation doesn't resume until after the while loop has finished.

Comment: Exactly, I edited my question with another example, focusing on my actual problem.

Comment: This worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/8p5Ah/5/ (not browser tested, just chrome)

Comment: Another option would be Web workers, but i have not tested this usecase yet. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers

Comment: Ok, I now understand that I should not talk about css animations, but rather css transitions. Should I post a different question for this matter? I also think that Web workers can be the solution for my issue.

Comment: The timeout solution works for your example up top also. I could be misunderstanding what you are asking, so feel free to ignore :).  http://jsfiddle.net/YWefx/14/

Comment: I don't believe this is working the way it should, as the loop() function will return as soon as the setTimeout instruction is called, the program will only build about 10 arrays before the loadingbar is full, but there will be still plenty of computing after that.

Comment: This one seems to work just like I wanted. I think that the large amount of setTimeout calls leave the browser with enough time to take care of the animations. http://jsfiddle.net/YWefx/17/

Comment: I went a little different route but came to almost the same conclusion.  This was a fun exercise, thanks.  http://jsfiddle.net/YWefx/21/

Comment: One last one for fun:  http://jsfiddle.net/YWefx/23/  This guesses how long the next iteration will take so the bar looks smoother.