# CSS transitions blocked by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css-transitions

I am trying to create a loading bar during a *very* intensive period of JavaScript where some pretty heavy 3d arrays are built and filled. This loading bar needs to remain empty until the user clicks a button.

The freezing occurs *whether or not* I'm using `-webkit-transition` (This app can be chrome exclusive, cross browser is not necessary in my case).

Seeking simplicity I've built my bar like this...

```
<div id="loader">
    <div id="thumb">
    </div>
</div>
```

... and then sought to increment that bar at various stages of my main `for` loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
    document.getElementById('thumb').style.width = i*25 + '%';
    //More Code
}
```

Problem is that everything freezes until the JavaScript finishes. 
I found a similar question on Stack Overflow, [Using CSS animation while javascript computes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752864/using-css-animation-while-javascript-computes), and in the comments found and considered and/or tried the following:

- Web Workers

  Don't think it'll work since my script is filling an array with objects and constructors containing functions which according to [this site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers) isn't going to work
- jQuery

  Not an option, I can't use external libraries in my app - in any case, importing a whole library just for a loading bar seems kind of like overkill...
- Keyframes

  This was promising and I tried it, but in the end it freezes also, so no joy
- `timeOut()`s

  Thought about this, but since the point of the loading bar is to reduce frustration, increasing the waiting time seems counter-productive

I'd be happy to have *any* incrementation of the bar at this stage, even if it's not smooth! I'm pretty sure this is a problem that has struck more than just me - maybe someone has an interesting solution?

*P.S.: I'm posting this as a new question rather than adding to the referenced question since I'm specifically seeking help with JavaScript (not jQuery) and would prefer if I could get it using a transition (!=animation) on the width.*

Comment: You can break your work up into pieces and chain the pieces together via timeouts. (At the end of one piece, schedule a timeout that runs the next piece.) This allows the browser to run animations in between each of the pieces.

Comment: As @RaymondChen indicated, your rationale for not using `window.setTimeout(…)` is not sound. That method does _not_ have the rest of the code (or the user) wait; it schedules code for later execution instead.

Comment: Thanks, but don't I need to add a delay? A delay of 0 wouldn't give time to transition as far as I know... As mentioned in the question, it seems counter-productive to make the user wait even more...

Comment: What about a delay of 10ms .. or even 5ms? barely noticeable ? give it a try!!

Comment: Oh... thanks RaymondChen & @PointedEars, I'll try it out some more and see...

Comment: @Paul I would recommend a timeout of not less than 50 ms. That aligns well with most system timers nowadays. Timeouts less than 10 ms will be capped to that value to avoid high CPU load.

Comment: Will keep that in mind cheers :) [#lovethestack]

Comment: Hmm... with a `timeOut(createMap(), 50)` no joy... still frozen 'til very end...

Comment: If you setup a test case on jsfiddle.net, I'll make this work for you.

Comment: This may just be a typeo, but `setTimeout(createMap(), 50)` will execute the function and assign the result to the setTimeout, likely not what you wanted. It should be something like: `setTimeout(createMap, 50)`.

Comment: Ah... it is a typo, but one I had made in the original code while testing... thanks for spotting it @tjameson!

Comment: Thanks @RaymondChen, your approach was the eventual answer to my problem, as given by meetamit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some people already mentioned that you should use timeouts. That's the appropriate approach, bc it'll give the browser time to "breathe" and render your progress bar mid-task.

You have to split your code up to work asynchronously. Say you currently have something like this:

```
function doAllTheWork() {
  for(var i = 0; i < reallyBigNumberOfIterations; i++) {
    processorIntensiveTask(i);
  }
}
```

Then you need to turn it into something like this:

```
var i = 0;
function doSomeWork() {
  var startTime = Date.now();
  while(i < reallyBigNumberOfIterations && (Date.now() - startTime) < 30) {
    processorIntensiveTask(i);
    i++;
  }

  if(i < reallyBigNumberOfIterations) {
    // Here you update the progress bar
    incrementBar(i / reallyBigNumberOfIterations);

    // Schedule a timeout to continue working on the heavy task
    setTimeout(doSomeWork, 50);
  }
  else {
    taskFinished();
  }
}

function incrementBar(fraction) {
  console.log(Math.round(fraction * 100) + ' percent done');
}

function taskFinished() { console.log('Done!'); }

doSomeWork();
```

Note the expression `(Date.now() - startTime) < 30`. That means the loop will get as much done as it can in the span of 30 milliseconds. You can make this number bigger, but anything over 100ms (essentially 10 frames-per-second) is going to start feeling sluggish from the user's point of view.

It may be true that the overall task is going to take somewhat longer using this approach as opposed to the synchronous version. However, from the user's experience, having an indication that *something* is happening is better than waiting indefinitely while *nothing* seems to be happening – even if the latter wait time is shorter.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it'll take a little while to implement with my code, but I'm thinking this is finally the way to go... Though currently I have 5 processor intensive tasks and have already tried a `timeOut()` between each and didn't get any reaction from the page tl the end of all five... but I'll try and come back to you.

Comment: Thanks very much, splitting it up like this has really helped (I still have work to do to get it just right, but the above answer is the best for my specific problem). Totally agree that the investment of (in my case at the moment) 600ms, which is almost a 25% increase from before just *feels* less frustrating seeing progress being made. Naturally I need to (and now can) improve and tweak that. Thanks @meetamit!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going even simpler and making a function, let's say:

Pseudo:

```
Function increment_bar(amount = 10)
{
 document.getElementById('thumb').style.width = i*amount + '%';
}
```

Then from wherever you are doing your processing work just calling that function every x seconds or whenever you hit a certain point in processing (let's say 10-20% completion?)

Pseudo:

```
{
    Doing_work_here;
    increment_bar(25);
    LOOP
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I haven't tried doing it from a specific function, I just made a call to `document.getElementById()` directly. I'll try it, but do you think it makes a difference that it's in a function or not? I'd find that surprising (but anything is possible!)

Comment: Nope... Bar just stays at 0, everything choked up until the end and then BAM! 100 % just before fadeout.
`function increment(input){
document.getElementById('thumb').style.width = input*25 + '%';
}`

Comment: Apologies - it's a shame that doesn't do it for you as it would of been simpler!

Comment: No worries @Paul, if it's any consolation I ended up using your approach in conjunction with the above answer :-D