# How to draw graphs using d3.js for a big dataset?

Tags: d3.js

I tried creating 10 linecharts all of them had 3000 points, 300*300  svg size. It crashed my browser, I checked task manager, google renderer was going crazy with memory utilization 1.2G and CPU utilization 100%.

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy solution for things like this. You can scrutinize your code and make it as efficient as possible, but no matter what, if your code needs to do hundreds of thousands of operations in one "thread" things will freeze up.

A general solution to avoid this freeze-up is to split the drawing process into smaller tasks, which you call asynchronously (i.e. from inside a `setTimeout`). This way the browser doesn't lock up for extended periods while it runs your JS code, and perhaps (I'm no expert on this) the garbage collector has a chance to clean things up midway too.

The result is not a faster overall draw time, but to a user it "feels" faster, because the browser doesn't freeze. And you can even add a progress bar then.

Some drawing operations can't be broken down into sub-tasks. For example, you can't split up `svg.line()`, the d3 function that generates your graph's path definitions. However, you *can* split up the drawing code of the 10 charts such that it draws one chart at a time on every tick of a `setTimeout`. You can also similarly split up the preparation of the data from the actual drawing.

I wrote an answer to a different scenario but a similar problem here: [CSS transitions blocked by JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461871/css-transitions-blocked-by-javascript/13462325#13462325)

Comment: I tried to split the drawing process, so instead of drawing all of the graphs, I added one collapsible menu and moved each graph under one tab, so when a user clicks on a tab the graph is plotted, but the problem is when I open all the tabs one by one, again same thing happens and my browser crashes.